# What is batch file and what is the real time use of batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file

I am new to java, Now i am learning. So i googled sample java websites. for example i downloaded source code for online reservation system.

In that code,it have `install.bat` and `start.bat` file. May i know what is the use of this file?

Can anyone explain me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess: `install.bat` install the application and `start.bat` starts the application. Look in the file and you should see if this is correct.

Comment: `install.bat` tells windows where to install app. `start.bat` gives direction to start the app. Nothing to do with java

Comment: @jens: yes i used,, i was run one application. so it used for install and start the variety of applications(java, .net, php..etc) right?

Comment: @selva I think so, but without seeing the content of the file I can not give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out what theese files do by taking a look inside. .bat files are written in plain text. Each line contain one or several commands that can be interpreted and executed by cmd.exe. This kind of files aren't only used for java but for lots of purposes. In your case they are used to launch a java program. In contrast to e.g. C++ Java won't give you an .exe file that you can start by doubleclicking on it. It compiles your code into a .jar file. In order to launch this file you must call the Java virtual machine and tell it to start your jar file (there are some more parameters which you don't have to care about while you are just starting with Java).

However, it will take a while till you'll have to deal with BATCH files. By now you should use your IDE (I would recomend Eclipse) which allows you to start your progrgam without taking care of how to do it. You just hit the "Play"-Button and get your result.

Comment: thanks @michaelS. already practicing simple java programs in using eclipse.

Comment: Good luck! :D You are on teh right way. You will get to batch files as soon as you'll have to run your programs outside of eclipse. At that point we will be glad to help you with further steps! :)

Comment: ok, if we created simple "hello world" java program right?.. so outside of eclipse, how to create a batch file for easy run?.. sorry for this trivial question, this is for further improvement of understanding

Comment: No problem, your questions are trivial but not stupid :) You are right, if you create a Hello World in Eclipse, you can export it to a jar file. Then you create a text file (in the same directory as your jar is - just to simplify it). In the text file you put the command: `java -jar yourprogram.jar`. Finally rename your file from .txt to .bat and run it. This will execute your hello world program outside of your IDE.

Comment: Thanks lot @michaelS.. so finally use of batch file only for java platform? or any other use?

Comment: In your case: yes, you only need bat files to run your programs on windows. Generally - well - you can do nearly everything with bat files :D Everything you can achieve from the cmd-console can be packed into bat files. CMD shell scripts are written in an own programming language and are used to put many lines cmd code lines in one file instead of typing them line by line in your cmd window.

Comment: If your are interested in cmd, you should take a look at this page: http://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: Sure. Currently I'm working as a C# software engineer but I still prefer Java.

Comment: i am beginner. so can you give some ideas about that?

Comment: I guess this question is too broad. There are countless tutorial websites out there. Just check them out, do some tutorials, try to understand simple code parts... As I'm german, I could only give you some german websites on Java but I guess that won't help you much :(

Comment: ok @michael: the problem is "There are countless tutorial websites out there in online" i just confused with one another. am an indian.can you provide some books, links..?/

Comment: As mentioned, the only good beginner books I know are in german. I've used this open book sometimes: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming. But I can't tell you whether there are better books out there. Instead of reading the whole book I'd recommend to get familiar with the Language. Then pick a simple project like a calculator and start coding untill you'r stuck. Then read how to master the step you're stuck with. Solve the problems using google, stackoverflow or the eBook as soon as they come up instead of reading the whole book and forgetting how it started as soon as you're done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66738/discussion-between-selva-and-michaels).

Answer (score 0):

They're nothing to do with Java *per se*.

They're Windows batch scripts, and from the names, it looks as though one of them is there to install the application on your machine, and one is there to start the application up.

Java is cross-platform, which is a strength for the most part, but it does mean that sometimes applications need a little bit of boilerplate code for starting the application on different platforms. So sometimes you will see Java applications that have a Windows batch file or similar for starting on Windows, and a shell script for starting on Linux, and so on.

Comment: yes @chiastic-security: this is nothing to do with java.. i am asking what is the purpose?..

Comment: @selva yes, I've tried to answer that too: it looks as though one is for installation on Windows, and one is for starting the application on Windows.

Comment: yes i used,, i was run one application. so it used for install and start the variety of applications(java, .net, php..etc) right? and if we have created any application , we need to create a batch file right?

Comment: @selva Not every application needs a batch file, no. A Windows program might be a `.exe` file, and a Java application might just be an executable `.jar` file; and in any case not all applications are designed to run on Windows!

Comment: hi are you there @chiastic-security

Answer (score 0):

Batch files with the extension .bat have nothing to do with Java. They are Windows-specific shell scripts, introduced with MS-DOS in 1981.

Comment: It makes me slightly queasy to see Windows batch files described as *shell scripts*, but I suppose the command processor just about qualifies as a shell :)

Comment: I was queasy writing it---but it's a good analogy for the lucky ones lacking first-hand experience with MS-DOS :)

Answer (score 0):

A set of multiple commands called as a batch file. Say you are been assigned to compile a set of classes, create jar file and execute. This can be done with a simple batch file like this:

activity1.bat

```
REM set java home path
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0
REM set path
set PATH=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0\bin
REM set class path
SET CLASSPATH=..
REM compile class files
javac -cp %CLASSPATH% %CUR_DIR%*.java
REM create a jar file
jar cfm new.jar Manifest.txt *.*
REM execute
java -cp %CLASSPATH%;new.jar MainClass.java
PAUSE
```

Note: REM meant for comments.

Comment: oh ok .. if we created one application in java(for example) then can we convert as batch file for easy to run right?

Comment: You can't convert Java to bat but you can make it easy to run by creating an additional bat file that will run your java program by simply starting the bat file.

Comment: Yes, also it will generally used by the administrators as and when required. Usually a batch file meant for a particualr operation with doesn't required any server. An administrator(who are not familiar with java commands execution) will simply execute it by double clicking on it.

Comment: Assumed convertion as specifying source details into a batch file!

Comment: @MichaelS: you are right, the way of my question is incorrect, how to run simply java program using batch file for simple "hello world" java program?

Comment: Let's assume you've exported your program using Eclipse and stored it at C:\MyProg\HelloWorld.jar. To run it, you create a .txt file in the same folder. In this file you put the command `java -jar HelloWorld.jar`. Rename the file from .txt to .bat and just start it. Et voilà, your program is running. If it is a simple output to the console you might add the line `@Pause` to your bat file. Otherwise the program will run and exit and you won't even notice.